# Error when writing python pandas dataframe to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a problem writing a Pandas dataframe to a csv file. I guess there are som characters that can not be translated but I do not know how to fix the problem. I need help on this.

Here is my simple call and the error message:

```
big_frame.to_csv('C:\DRO\test.csv')
```

error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.write_csv_rows (pandas\lib.c:13528)()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using a different file encoding: 
`big_frame.to_csv('C:\DRO\test.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: It just lets python know what kind of data it's writing (e.g., ascii, unicode). As the error message says, ascii (the default) can't deal with unicode characters (\xd6)